# Xamarin.Forms IOS disable change of device theme affect on App design

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, themes

I have finished my app. When i install on IOS and the theme is dark , entries ,pickers etc backgroud color is black. How to disable change of themes affect the application?

Comment: If you want to disable the dark mode. Try to set the property `UIUserInterfaceStyle` to `Light` in the `info.plist`. like this thread: https://zonneveld.dev/how-to-support-dark-mode-in-ios-apps/

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT and when user in his phone add Dark Mode it wont affect on my app?

Comment: Yes, if you add the property, your application will be light mode if user change the dark mode.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT add answer so i can check it

Comment: Done, please check it.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT i also get dark permssion dialog. How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your description, if you want to disable the dark mode.

Try to set the property `UIUserInterfaceStyle` to `Light` in the `info.plist`.

If you add the property, your application will be light mode if user change the dark mode.

[image]